# vim per file sourcing, similar to modelines

Tags: vim

Is it possible to have vim automatically source a file consisting of (for instance) imaps if one is editing a particular file. Not a filetype, but one particular file. Ideally, I could set imaps in modelines but this is not possible.

The context is that I am editing a long LaTeX file and rather than define innumerable \newcommands I would prefer to have vim type the TeX for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with autocommands in your .vimrc.

```
aug MyLaTeXEnvironnementForMyFile
  au!
  au BufRead /pattern/to/*/path/to/my/file :so /the/relevant/script.vim
aug END
```

The file loaded this way shall be written in the same way we'd write a ftplugin (buffer local mappings, commands, settings, abbreviations).

NB: I prefer to use a [local .vimrc](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/local_vimrc.vim) that I drop in the directory where is the file for which I have a specific environment. This way I can move my file around, or share the settings between several files very easily without having to edit my .vimrc. 
See also: [Vim: apply settings on files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory/456889#456889)