# Set compiler includes (-I) with c.vim plugin?

Tags: c, vim, compiler-construction

I've been setting up vim to us as my C/C++ IDE recently and have been really impressed with the c.vim plugin (found [here](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=213)). However, I'm working on a project that relies on a library that is not found in my system includes. When I compile manually, I just list this directory by passing g++ an include flag (e.g. g++ -I ~/lib/). Is there any way to set up c.vim to have this directory included when I use the "save and compile" ("\rc" by default) command?

Thanks!

Comment: You might check the documentation hier: http://lug.fh-swf.de/vim/vim-doc/csupport.html#csupport-custom-glob-vars It's done via the var/s mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd would just set `$CXXFLAGS` to `-I~/lib`, it's its job -- unless you are using the dumb makefile default configuration from mingw project, $CXXFLAGS will be recognized automagically, as long as your `&makeprg` still points to `make` and not directly to g++ or any other compiler (I don't know what c.vim does with this vim setting as I don't use it).

As I suspect you don't have any Makefile in your directory but just a monofile project, I'd prefer an [extended modeline](http://code.google.com/p/lh-vim/source/browse/misc/trunk/plugin/let-modeline.vim) over [project settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory/456889#456889).