# VIM -- apply local vimrc file

Tags: vim

I want to be able to have a file with some highlight choices local to the current directory, generally used to highlight certain phrases in a log file as I am analyzing it.

I found this:

```
if filereadable("_gvimrc")
    source _gvimrc
endif
```

In this question:
[Vim: apply settings on files in directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory/13192721#13192721)

Which works when starting the editor.   However, when switching between files, say "file1.log" and "file2.log" the highlighting is wiped away as the local _gvimrc is not sourced each time a file is opened, only when vim is started.

Is there a way to reload the local commands file every time a file is opened?

Comment: This smells a lot like an XY problem. Could you tell us *how* that highlighting is done?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments of the linked answer, there are many issues with the suggested command. The fact that you lose your highlighting when you edit another file is a sign that a) you are probably doing that highlighting in a suboptimal way, and b) that you are also doing it at the wrong place. It is hard to be more specific with the little information you gave us.

In general, commands you put in `*vimrc` files are executed once during startup and in the global scope, which makes it unfit for local, file-specific commands like:

```
match Foo 'foo\sbar'
```

You would need to execute it with an autocommand for it to be really usable. Something like:

```
autocmd! BufRead *.log match SomeHighLightGroup 'foo\sbar'
```

Now, if I wanted to systematically have the phrase `foo bar` highlighted in yellow and the phrase `baz quux` highlighted in blue in all `*.log` files under `/path/to/logs/`, I would do it like this:

1. Create an ad-hoc syntax script under `syntax/mylogs.vim` with something like this as content:

   ```
   hi Yellow ctermbg=yellow ctermfg=black
   hi Blue ctermbg=blue ctermfg=black
   syn match Yellow 'foo\sbar'
   syn match Blue 'baz\squux'
   ```

   Where I…

   - define two different highlight groups, `Yellow` and `Blue`
   - use the syntax highlighting mechanism to match the desired phrases.

   See `:help syntax`.
2. Tell Vim to assign the `mylogs` syntax to every `*.log` file under `/path/to/logs/`:

   ```
   " in my vimrc
   augroup mylogs
       autocmd!
       autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile /path/to/logs/*.log set syntax=mylogs
   augroup END
   ```

   Where I…

   - define a self-clearing autocommand group
   - and use a simple autocommand to achieve our goal.

   See `:help :augroup`, `:help :autocmd`, `:help BufRead`, `:help BufNewFile`, `:help 'syntax'`, and more generally, `:help new-filetype`.

The net effect of this is that, every time I edit a `*.log` under `/path/to/logs/`, I effortlessly get `foo bar` and `baz quux` highlighted the way I want:

[image: highlights]

If I needed to add new phrases, I would only have to add more lines to the syntax script:

```
hi Green ctermbg=green ctermfg=black
syn match Green 'patapouf'
```

and, eventually, reapply the syntax with:

```
:set syntax=mylogs
```

or simply:

```
:e
```

[image: highlighting]

Comment: Thank you.  I will have to read through this as it has a lot of information.  It sounds like autocmd is definately what I would like, not sure I want/need to link the formatting to a specific extension.  It is more like when I edit any file in this directory, use the local highlighting file.  Which it does when you start, but not when you change files.  thanks again for the info, but I have to wade through it all to see if autocmd really does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in the comments of the approach you have chosen, *"you can only work on one project at the time"*. And this is exactly what you observe: the configuration file is only loaded at vim start-up.

If you really don't want to use a plugin for this purpose, [`:h 'exrc'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27exrc%27) may be enough if you don't have directory hierarchies.

If you're not afraid of clobbering your .vimrc with project specific autocommands, there is the second part of Romain's solution -- the first, and very clever, part could be applied to any approach (you could define syntax files in your `~/.vim/syntax/` directory, and source them from local_vimrc/.exrc/...)